# Pentaho Data Integrator - MongoDB Input - JSONParseException

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to use the MongoDB input step in Pentaho 9.4.

It's my first time working with MongoDb.
I made a simple query, and ran it in RobotMongo.

```
db.history.aggregate( [ { $match: {_insertedDate: {$gte:ISODate("2023-07-26T00:00:00Z")}} }, { $group:{_id:{originalSummary:"$originalSummary"}} } ] )
```

Returns values normally.
[image: Result]

When taking this same query, and puting it to the PDI, I can't run it.
What am I doing wrong?

Error:

```
2023/07/26 19:54:36 - MongoDB input.0 - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2023/07/26 19:54:36 - MongoDB input.0 - com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{ $match: {_insertedDate: {$gte: ISODate("2023-07-26T00:00:00Z")}} }
                                ^
2023/07/26 19:54:36 - MongoDB input.0 - 
{ $match: {_insertedDate: {$gte: ISODate("2023-07-26T00:00:00Z")}} }
                                ^
2023/07/26 19:54:36 - MongoDB input.0 - 
2023/07/26 19:54:36 - MongoDB input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mongodbinput.MongoDbInput.processRow(MongoDbInput.java:155)
2023/07/26 19:54:36 - MongoDB input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2023/07/26 19:54:36 - MongoDB input.0 -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2023/07/26 19:54:36 - MongoDB input.0 - Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{ $match: {_insertedDate: {$gte:ISODate("2023-07-26T00:00:00Z")}} }
                                ^
2023/07/26 19:54:36 - MongoDB input.0 -     at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:232)
```

Pentaho:
[image: Configuration]

Comment: Have you tried changing the dates into [MongoDB extended JSON format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-Date)? i.e. put them in `{"date": ...}`

Comment: @ray Dude, great tip. It worked by changing to this format.
Thank you so much, I didn't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official MongoDB doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Date/#return-date-as-date-object),

> `mongosh` wraps objects of Date type with the ISODate helper; however, the objects remain of type Date.

My interpretation is that `ISODate` may not be available elsewhere. It may be sensible to use [MongoDB extended JSON format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-Date) for your case.